# Is the fact that a question is older and downvoted a good reason to reject an edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

I was cleaning up some questions for the Homework tag, and I was told that I shouldn't bother since it is an old question, is this true. 
It happened in 2 occasions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1490694) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1490715) by the same user. 
Along the lines of this,

> Why bother? It's a -2-voted question, closed, from years ago.

Comment: I don't think the user (Kurt Revis) wanted to reject it. But it's the only way to provide feedback. He's basically telling you to stop wasting time on crap posts that are closed and probably should be deleted anyway.

Comment: Part of the reason for the cleanup is that many of the questions in that tag are just bad and need to be removed.  If you want to help clean up, [sort questions tagged homework by votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework?sort=votes&pagesize=50).  Better questions will be upvoted, so they'll have a better chance of not getting deleted later.  Just remember to remove the tag *and* fix anything else you see wrong with a question when you suggest an edit.

Comment: the fact that a question is older and downvoted is a good reason to **skip review** to let it be handled by someone who could better understand given suggested edit and evaluate it without having doubts about question age and score

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When it comes to closed questions, your time (and the reviewers' time) would be better spent improving questions that actually have a chance of getting re-opened. Neither of your examples is salvageable, they should both be deleted.

As a sidenote, when a post you successfully suggested an edit on is deleted, you lose the 2 rep bonus.

Comment: And, as suggestions need to be reviewed, *"your time"* might actually read *"everyone's time"*.

Answer (score 1):

Edits should ideally fix everything that's wrong with the post, or at least take a major step towards this goal. It's only worth editing a closed question if your edit gives it a chance at being reopened. I don't mean that you should only edit sure-fire reopen candidates, but stick to editing questions for which the cleaned-up version looks reasonably good, or for which the edit makes a dramatic difference (e.g. translating a post in a foreign language). Editing a post that's on its way to deletion anyway is a waste of time. I would have rejected both your examples as “too minor”, because the questions are unsalvageable.

Regarding [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) specifically, please **do** remove the tag on questions that shouldn't be closed (and fix everything else that needs fixing — formatting, tags, grammar, etc.), and **do not** remove the tag on questions that should be closed and deleted (but do cast a flag to close). Users with sufficient privilege look for questions with the tag to close or delete; removing the tag removes these questions from the cleanup radar.